# Python code to replace strings in a text file using using other mapping text file

Tags: python, string, replace, mapping

I need to replace many strings in my sql codes due to a big change in their structure.
I have other file with a mapping that I need to use to replace those strings.

Let's say this is my sample code text in which I need to replace values
(of course in reality the code is hundred of lines):

```
select * from xyz.def
where line_chart in
('abc12345','cde23456','fgh34567','ijk45678','lmn56789')
```

and the mapping text:

```
abc12345:bbb222
cde23456:ddd333
fgh34567:fff444
ijk45678:hhh555
lmn56789:jjj666
```

What is the best way to do that?
Thank you guys.

Comment: first don't search the best way but working way. So first try do to anything. ie. `for`-loop with `.replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody needs this, I figured it out:

```
mapping = open(path, 'r')
data_dict = {}
for line in mapping:
    k, v = line.strip().split(':')
    data_dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()


code_file = open(path2, "r")
tempstr = code_file.read()
code_file.close()


def replace_words(base_text, device_values):
    for key, val in device_values.items():
        base_text = base_text.replace(key, val)
    return base_text


output = replace_words(tempstr, data_dict)


file_out = open(path3, 'w')
file_out.write(output)
```